# how to decode the bytearray(which is in .h264 format) in to video by using jcodec?

Tags: android, decode, live-streaming

In My App,I have to decode the bytearray(that is in .h264 format) in to video and the bytearray coming from live steaming.The code is below,

```
static final int VIDEO_BUF_SIZE = 100000;
 static final int FRAME_INFO_SIZE = 16;
 byte[] frameInfo = new byte[FRAME_INFO_SIZE];
 byte[] videoBuffer = new byte[VIDEO_BUF_SIZE];

File SDFile = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

File destDir = new File(SDFile.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.h264");


//avRecvFrameData returns the length of the frame and stores it in ret.
int ret = av.avRecvFrameData(avIndex, videoBuffer,
                        VIDEO_BUF_SIZE, frameInfo, FRAME_INFO_SIZE,
                        frameNumber);

fos=new FileOutputStream(destDir,true);
                fos.write(videoBuffer, 0, ret);
                fos.close();
```

Here how can i decode the videobuffer(bytearray)?

So what Can I do now.

Thanks to All.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official android api to decode a H.264 frame directly, the only way is porting ffmpeg to android and wrap the decode function with jni.